# Automatic parallelization with gfortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to speed up a quite lengthy program that was originally not designed for parallel computing. I'm therefore experimenting with automatic parallelization with `gfortran`.

I have the following test program, that basically just performs some loops and is measuring the execution time:

```
program autoparallel

    implicit none

    integer                       :: N = 10000
    double precision, allocatable :: A(:, :), X(:), Y(:)

    integer                       :: i, j
    integer                       :: time_start, time_finish, time_rate

    call system_clock ( time_start, time_rate )

    allocate( A(N, N), X(N), Y(N) )

    do i=1, N
        do j=1, N
            A(i, j) = i * j
        end do
    end do

    do i=1, N
        X(i) = i
    end do

    do i=1, N
        Y(i) = 0.d0
    end do

    do i=1, N
        do j=1, N
            Y(i) = Y(i) + A(j, i) * X(j)
        end do
    end do

    call system_clock ( time_finish, time_rate )

    write(*,*) 'Elapsed time: ', (time_finish-time_start)/real(time_rate), ' seconds'

    write(*,*) Y(1), Y(N)

    deallocate(A, X, Y)

end program autoparallel
```

I executed it with different compiler flags five times each:

```
gfortran test.f90
4.14799976      seconds
4.51900005      seconds
4.42399979      seconds
4.15600014      seconds
4.38000011      seconds

gfortran -floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=2 autoparallel.f90
4.36899996      seconds
4.07499981      seconds
4.35599995      seconds
4.17899990      seconds
4.37500000      seconds

gfortran -floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=4 autoparallel.f90
4.28399992      seconds
4.42600012      seconds
4.19999981      seconds
4.33199978      seconds
4.14499998      seconds

gfortran -O3 autoparallel.f90
3.63599992      seconds
3.63599992      seconds
3.79800010      seconds
3.55900002      seconds
3.59599996      seconds

gfortran -O3 -floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=4 autoparallel.f90
3.09299994      seconds
3.08299994      seconds
3.46799994      seconds
3.00099993      seconds
3.00699997      seconds

gfortran -O3 -floop-nest-optimize autoparallel.f90
1.03100002      seconds
1.01800001      seconds
1.02300000      seconds
1.03600001      seconds
0.947000027      seconds
```

So basically the execution time is flat with the number of threads. Only after optimization the automatic parallelization kicks in.
I'm trying to understand why this is.

At least all of the `i`-loops could be distributed over multiple threads without any optimization.

So what is exactly going on here? And are there other compiler flags that I could use to further speed up the program? And what flags would be conflicting my goal of parallelization?

`-floop-nest-optimize` doesn't work together with `-floop-parallelize-all`. 
Error:

```
isl_constraint.c:497: position out of bounds
```

Comment: A smart optimising compiler (and optimising compilers can be pretty smart) would realize that nothing is done with the value of `Y`, so therefore it doesn't need to bother with the loops that define `Y`.  Similarly it would then realize that it doesn't need to bother defining `X` and `A`.  That would collapse the entire program down to some timer queries and some output statements.  I haven't investigated whether gfortran does this or not (the times suggest not), but with optimisation enabled you may not be executing what you think you are.

Comment: The first loop is an obvious candidate for loop nest switching, but I don't count on gfortran to find that automatically.  Nor do I count on gfortran performing an automatic dot_product substitution in the last one.

Comment: Putting "print *, Y(1), Y(N)" before deallocate() may be useful to avoid possible dead-code elimination thing. With gfort-6.1 on osx10.9, attaching -floop-nest-optimize made the calculation almost twice as fast @@ (I didn't know these parallel (?) options so very interesting...)

Comment: That's a good point. I edited the original post. `-floop-nest-optimize` doesn't work together with autoparallelization.

Comment: The parallelization won't scale that well because your operations are memory bandwith limited, not limited by CPU speed.

Comment: I tried a bit more with other parallel & vector (-ish) options by looking at gcc-6 man page, but I could not get additional speedup... RE the reason why -O0 did not scale, my wild guess is that it is simply turned off at -O0 level, because all combinations of options gave the same speed (on osx10.9).

Answer (score 1):

I find that that third loop is usually improved with OpenMP REDUCTION (or !DIR$ DO SIMD reduction on ifort).

```
USE OMPLIB
....
do i=1, N
    !$OMP DO SIMD REDUCTION(+:Y)
    do j=1, N
        Y(i) = Y(i) + A(j, i) * X(j)
    end do
end do
```

And with some work perhaps the Y(I) could be PRIVATE to be parallel over the I loop. Unless the work load is a high it rarely makes as much improvement to parallelize over the I loop for these simple cases.

YRMV

Comment: Of course OpenMP directives can be added in many places of the code. The question is about automatic threading and why it does not scale well with the number of threads. The SIMD directives can speed up the base code, but I doubt it will cure the scaling. It may actually hurt it (faster code is harder to make more faster.)

Comment: And note that this may prevent the nest optimization.

Comment: @Vladimir what is a "tour operation"?  The point of the SIMD is that this is, by inspection, good for a vector optimisation... And not so much so for a parallel optimization. Most of the time it take some effort to determine where and how to get a speed up.

Comment: "tour <-> your" Notice the question is about automatic parallelization. Not how to manually optimize given simplified code sample.

Comment: Yup... I would move that first clock down before the loop doing all the work. The time to allocate and zero the arrays or initializing them can detracting from getting a more precise measurement of the work timing.